# Check if file exists while looping array

Tags: bash

Well, I really did my research and read many of the "how to check if a file exists and touch" questions. But I'm still missing something.

Here I'm trying to create a simple json file which should later contain an array of dictionaries. The dictionary objects are each stored in the ios_tut_meta array. 
The objects are written to the file tutorials_meta.json as they should, but my file existence check never goes into the "else" part, thus I'm missing to write a comma separator for my objects.

... Why is the file check not working? Is that a sub shell issue?

```
# Write the meta info for the pages into tutorials_meta.json:
# {[{file: "123.html", title: "First Deep Map"}]}
file_ex="$tutorials_dir_ios/.meta"
rm  "$file_ex"
echo "[" > "$tutorials_dir_ios/tutorials_meta.json"
for ios_meta in "${ios_tut_meta[@]}"
do
    if [ ! -f "$file_ex" ]; then
       touch "$file_ex"
    else 
       echo "," >> "$tutorials_dir_ios/tutorials_meta.json"
    fi 
    echo "$ios_meta" >> "$tutorials_dir_ios/tutorials_meta.json"
done
echo "]" >> "$tutorials_dir_ios/tutorials_meta.json"

echo "tutorials dir: $tutorials_dir_ios"
echo "meta: ${ios_tut_meta[@]}"
```

The above two variables contain the following values:

```
tutorials dir: tmp/tutorials/ios
meta: {"file":"29855709.html","title":"First Map Application [iOS]"}   
{"file":"29860078.html","title":"Map Annotations [iOS]"}
{"file":"29860406.html","title":"Map Deployment and Update [iOS]"}    
{"file":"29860277.html","title":"Routing [iOS]"}
```

### Solved

I've added items to the array this way:

```
ios_tut_meta+=$(printf '{"file":"%s","title":"%s"}\n' "$i.html" "$title")
```

I intended to write the right part enclosed in braces. But my tired eyes didn't catch it. So that was what I wanted to write:

```
ios_tut_meta+=($(printf '{"file":"%s","title":"%s"}\n' "$i.html" "$title"))
```

But that would also be wrong, because it splits the results from the subshell into several array items. The correct thing for what I wanted to do, namely add a single string to the array (that's actually a stringified json object):

```
   meta_obj=$(printf '{"file":"%s","title":"%s"}\n' "$i.html" "$title")
   ios_tut_meta+=("$meta_obj")
```

Comment: You are removing the `"$file_ex"` at first, so unless you modify the variable after that `[ ! -e "$file_ex" ]` will always be true..also where is `$tutorials_dir_ios` and `${ios_tut_meta[@]}` defined?

Comment: -e should be -f (I was experimenting..) and the if clause should check if the file exists each loop. So the "else" should be entered every loop but the first.

Comment: Well, we need to know whats the values of `${ios_tut_meta[@]}` array and variable `$tutorials_dir_ios`?

Comment: echo "tutorials dir: $tutorials_dir_ios"
echo "meta: ${ios_tut_meta[@]}"
=>
tutorials dir: tmp/tutorials/ios
meta: {"file":"29855709.html","title":"First Map Application [iOS]"}{"file":"298

Comment: Please add these to your question..

Comment: Thank you @heemayl your question led me to look again at the array itself. I was already digging into sub shell issues.